# Bash scripting: Illegal alias names

Tags: bash, shell

I was messing around with my .bash_profile file (Mac OSX) and when I tried to set an alias as such:

> alias .=". ~/.bash_profile"

I would not subsequently be able to source my .bash_profile file (typed "source .bash_profile" after exiting the file and was stuck in a non-terminating process). When I changed the alias to:

> alias s=". ~/.bash_profile"

Everything worked fine. What's the deal?

Comment: Isn't `.` already aliased? I don't think bash will allow you to reassign it. You are trying to reassign the alias for `source` I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the file called (in this case, `~/.bash_profile`) also uses `.`, a recursive call happens since `.` would refer to same file again.

Let's say if `~/.bash_profile` tries to call `~/.bashrc` with this line:

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

The command would expand first as an alias and it would instead be like this:

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bash_profile ~/.bashrc
```

Which would make the real `.` call `~/.bash_profile` instead and just have `~/.bashrc` as a positional parameter argument. This makes the infinite loop.

To reproduce:

1. `~.bash_profile` must exist and contains a line that calls another file with `.`.
2. Run `alias .="echo -n x; . ~/.bash_profile"; .`.

It should produce infinite `x` until shell crashes.

Comment: I thought this was the problem but I couldn't reproduce this in a quick test. Did you manage to reproduce it?

Comment: @EtanReisner The file has to exist. And it needs to be ran interactively. One thing as well: `~/.bash_profile` itself should call `.` as well.

Comment: Ah, the "some other line must also use `.`" bit is what I think I was missing.